# Why is PHP base_convert giving a different result to the same MYSQL function?

Tags: php, mysql

I've put together a PHP function as follows:

```
function keyword_hash($keyword) {
  return base_convert(substr(md5($keyword), -16), 16, 10);
}
```

The aim of this function is to generate a numeric hash value that I can store in a database, and use that for a look up (rather than trying to index a keyword column).

The equivalent of this function in MySQL is as follows:

```
SELECT CONV(RIGHT(MD5('some keyword'), 16), 16, 10);
```

I've verified that the MD5 string is the same, and the substr() matches the value I get back from RIGHT() in the MySQL query. However, when I run CONV(), I'm getting a different value to what's generated from base_convert().

For example, using `keyword_hash("some keyword")` generates a value of 10923672322315740844. However, using `SELECT CONV(RIGHT(MD5('some keyword'), 16), 16, 10)` generates 10923672322315740475, which shows the last three numbers as being different.

What am I missing here? Shouldn't they produce the same value?

Comment: [php.net](http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php)> base_convert() may lose precision on large numbers due to properties related to the internal "double" or "float" type used. Please see the Floating point numbers section in the manual for more specific information and limitations.

Comment: Why not trying to think on another way to achieve a numeric hash?

Comment: @Mogria Spot on, that was a great help, and pointed me in the direction of this comment http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php#109660, which has a great function to be more precise. Just tested it, and it returns the same values. Add your comment as an answer, and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: It would probably make more sense to just index on your hash. Even SHA1 is only 40 bytes in hex format.

Comment: @tadman Using this method, I can store this as a BIGINT, which is just 8 bytes. I don't need exact uniqueness either, just enough to improve efficiency and keep collisions to a minimum.

Comment: You shouldn't be sweating it over the slightly larger storage requirement. What's nice about storing hashes in hex is you can easily query them without any conversion required, just use the built-in hash function. Saving a handful of bytes per row at the expense of significant complexity in the age of terabyte-sized disks is usually pointless.

Comment: @tadman Interesting, thanks for the advice, will certainly consider it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took a look at the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php) page for `base_convert()`. There is the following **warning**:

> **base_convert()** may lose precision on large numbers due to properties related
> to the internal "double" or "float" type used. Please see the
> [Floating point numbers section](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) in the manual for more
> specific information and limitations.

Later in the [comments someone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php#109660) already found a solution for this problem (thanks @CraigSefton):

```
function str_baseconvert($str, $frombase=10, $tobase=36) { 
    $str = trim($str); 
    if (intval($frombase) != 10) { 
        $len = strlen($str); 
        $q = 0; 
        for ($i=0; $i<$len; $i++) { 
            $r = base_convert($str[$i], $frombase, 10); 
            $q = bcadd(bcmul($q, $frombase), $r); 
        } 
    } 
    else $q = $str; 
  
    if (intval($tobase) != 10) { 
        $s = ''; 
        while (bccomp($q, '0', 0) > 0) { 
            $r = intval(bcmod($q, $tobase)); 
            $s = base_convert($r, 10, $tobase) . $s; 
            $q = bcdiv($q, $tobase, 0); 
        } 
    } 
    else $s = $q; 
  
    return $s; 
}
```

This function uses the [bc math](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) library which supports arbitrary precision mathematics because it uses strings to store the numbers instead of integers/floats etc.